# Sort 'search results' based on the position of the 'search term' in them

Tags: laravel, sorting, search, filtering

I want to **order the results** showing those that **start with the letters the user is typing first**.

```php
public $search = "";

public function render()
{
    $business = Empresa::where("name", "like", "%" . $this->search . "%")
        ->orderBy("name")
        ->take(5)
        ->get();
    return view('livewire.general.simpleSearch', compact("business"));
}
```

---

My website currently shows the results like this:

[image]

---

Instead, when the user types `mer` I want to display the results like this:

[image]

Comment: Hey! If your question answered, mark the answer and upvote others to trying to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
    public function render()
    {
        $search = $this->search;

        $business = Empresa::where("name", "like", "%$search%")
            ->get();

        $sorted = $business->sortBy(function ($result) use ($search) {
            return strpos($result->name, $search);
        })->take(5);

        return view('livewire.general.simpleSearch')
            ->with('business', $sorted->values()->all());
    }
```

Comment: Not really, actually it shows the results in the same way I already was showing them, but thanks anyway

Comment: @OmarGB sorry but **we invested time and energy** to propose solution that finally work (*To finally get votes and reputation points ...*). So the least thing you can do after getting our engagement is giving us a useful feedback, like `dump($business)` and `dump($sorted)` from the code that I proposed so I get what I did wrong and improve my answer if I can.

Comment: when I wrote your code this is the result: https://imgur.com/a/jGZ2G2v.
what I was looking for was to have "Mercado Libre" first, and all the names that start with "Me" and then now all the rest of names that have "me" inside their names oreder

Comment: @OmarGB yes I understood and that's what the `sortBy` callback is doing with `strpos`. Also I tried that on one of my projects, that is why I need to see the `dump`s

Comment: medilies, I did it!!! THANKS! From your code using the explanation given by gguney I erased   orderBy("nombre")  and now it shows in the expected way: https://imgur.com/RUdwsyQ

Answer (score 1):

You try this
`Empresa::where("name", "like", $this->search . "%")->take(5)->get();`

Answer (score 0):

You should not put % before your query

```
$business = Empresa::where("name", "LIKE", $this->search . "%")->orderBy("name")->take(5)->get();
```

In sql when using LIKE query % act as wildcard. If you put % before your search string it will search ending with your string, if you put % after your search string it will search starting with your string. Since you put % before and after your search string it will search every row contains your search query.

Comment: @gguney I feel you XD, that's depressing. people get answers then ghost us. Is there a way to flag this behaviour ?

Comment: Actually none of the answers worked in the way I was looking for, but I didn't want to ask for more help so just thanked all of you.

Comment: You can at least upvote then

Comment: @gguney he can't vote :p

Comment: @medilies ah you are right.

Comment: WHen i tried this happened: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Comment: Can you try it again

Comment: THANKS!! gguney your explanation lead me to the answer.